# Apply function over data frame rows

Tags: r, purrr, rowwise

I'm trying to apply a function over the rows of a data frame and return a value based on the value of each element in a column. I'd prefer to pass the whole dataframe instead of naming each variable as the actual code has many variables - this is a simple example.

I've tried `purrr map_dbl` and `rowwise` but can't get either to work. Any suggestions please?

```
#sample df
df <- data.frame(Y=c("A","B","B","A","B"),
                  X=c(1,5,8,23,31))

#required result
Res <- data.frame(Y=c("A","B","B","A","B"),
                  X=c(1,5,8,23,31),
                  NewVal=c(10,500,800,230,3100)
                  )

#use mutate and map or rowwise etc
Res <- df %>%
  mutate(NewVal=map_dbl(.x=.,.f=FnAdd(.)))

Res <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(NewVal=FnAdd(.))


#sample fn
FnAdd <- function(Data){

  if(Data$Y=="A"){
    X=Data$X*10
  }  

  if(Data$Y=="B"){
    X=Data$X*100
  } 
  return(X)
}
```

Comment: I know, but this is just a simple example, there are about 20 similar functions each taking many variables. I'm looking for a clean way to do this.

Comment: @Zeus Could you please provide an example that reproduces your problem

Comment: if you run either of the methods I tried you should get the same error as me

Comment: @Zeus If you have 100 unique elements and the values to be multiplied are also kind of custom, then it is better to create the keyval dataset manually.  The `ifelse` route may not work as there is a limitation for the number of nested ifelse and would be slow

Comment: my mistake, 100 rows to process, 2 unique values to decide on which calculation type to use. ``ifelse`` is good and simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are multiple values, it is better to have a `key/val` dataset, join and then do the mulitiplication

```
keyVal <- data.frame(Y = c("A", "B"), NewVal = c(10, 100))
df %>%
   left_join(keyVal) %>%
   mutate(NewVal = X*NewVal)
#  Y  X NewVal
#1 A  1     10
#2 B  5    500
#3 B  8    800
#4 A 23    230
#5 B 31   3100
```

---

It is not clear how many unique values are there in the actual dataset 'Y' column.  If we have only a few values, then `case_when` can be used

```
FnAdd <- function(Data){
   Data %>%
      mutate(NewVal = case_when(Y == "A" ~ X * 10,
                                Y == "B" ~ X *100,
                                TRUE ~ X)) 
}

FnAdd(df)
#   Y  X NewVal
#1 A  1     10
#2 B  5    500
#3 B  8    800
#4 A 23    230
#5 B 31   3100
```

Comment: This doesn't replicate ``Req`` in the question.

Comment: @orizon  Can u check now?

Comment: Is there no way to build the if..else logic in the function? A different result/calculation depending on the value of a row element in one of the columns

Comment: @Zeus Sure, but could you tell us how many unique elements are there in the 'Y' column?

Comment: there will be 2 unique elements. This is just a simple example to show the logic I need. I'd like to pass the whole df and reference the variables in the function, and change the function result depending on one of the elements

Comment: @Zeus In that case, it is better to create a key/val dataset with unique keys and values corresponding to that

Comment: is there anyway to do something like this:
``Res <- df %>%
  mutate(NewVal=FnAdd(.))

#sample fn
FnAdd <- function(Data){
  
  NewVal = case_when(Data$Y == "A" ~ Data$X * 10,
                    Data$Y == "B" ~ Data$X *100,
                    TRUE ~ X) 
}``

Comment: I get an error ``Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'Y' not found`` when I run your solution

Comment: @Zeus  I am using `dplyr_0.7.2`.  Which version you have?

Answer (score 1):

You were originally looking for a solution using `dplyr's rowwise`() function, so here is that solution.  The nice thing about this approach is that you don't need to create a separate function.

Here's the version using if()

```
   df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(NewVal = ifelse(Y == "A", X * 10,
                          ifelse(Y == "B", X * 100)))
```

and here's the version using case_when:

```
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(NewVal = case_when(Y == "A" ~ X * 10,
                             Y == "B" ~ X * 100))
```